# Am I correct on my answers on sample space and probability?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is really simple question, but I'm quite new to this concept of sample space and probability. I hope to get my answeres checked for my understanding.

"Suppose that on a true/false exam you have no idea at all about the answers to three questions. You choose answers randomly and therefore have a 50–50 chance of being correct on any one question. Let CCW indicate that you were correct on the first two questions and wrong on the third, let WCW indicate that you were wrong on the first and third questions and correct on the second, and so forth.

a. List the elements in the sample space whose out comes are all possible sequences of correct and incorrect responses on your part.
b. Write each of the following events as a set and find its probability:
(i) The event that exactly one answer is correct."

My answer
a. {CCC, CCW, WCC, CWC, WWC, CWW, WCW, WWW}

b (i) {WWC, CWW, WCW}, 8/3

FYI. "The set of outcomes that can result from a random process or experiment is called a sample space."

[image]

Source: Discrete Mathematics with Applications. Susanna S. Epp

Comment: Everything was fine, except the probability is $3/8$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it mostly right, expect that the probability would be $3/8$, not $8/3$. Think of it as 8 students all following the same strategy -- on average, you'd expect 3 students to get exactly one answer right. The 'sample space', denoted $S$ in the picture, is nothing but all possible outcomes, and $E$ is a set of some specific outcomes you care about: in this case, as you correctly wrote, $E = \{CWW, WCW, WWC\}$.